# How to mate propane regulator to ozark trail camp stove

Tags: propane

I have a 20 lb. propane tank, a low pressure regulator hose, and an Ozark Trail camp stove.  I tried to set it up today and found that the end of the regulator hose did not mate with the stove.  It felt like the connector on the hose was too large to catch the threads on the stove inlet.

Here is the label from the regulator hose.
[image]

And here are the parts I'm trying to connect.  The silver part is the connector that attaches to the little propane canisters that you might take camping. It fits fine (but the other end won't fit on the 20 lb tank of course).  The brass is the end of the regulator hose that seems a little too big.

[image]

Is there some kind of an adapter that will work here?

Comment: https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/coleman-stove-propane-adapter as one example - lots of companies make such adapters, used by many stove manufacturers.

Comment: @JonCuster this looks like an entire new hose, and it doesn't look like it has a pressure regulator.  I was hoping that a simple coupling would mate the hose I have with the stove.  Ever seen something like that?

Comment: Yes, I have such hoses for both a Coleman and a Partner stove.